# Behavior Subject RXJS

Tags: rxjs, angular7, ionic4, behaviorsubject, angular-changedetection

I have this link that changes the final of the url with a time stamp:

```
  getAvatar(channelId): BehaviorSubject<string> {
    return new BehaviorSubject(`${link}?${new Date().getTime()}`);
  }
```

And in the Avatar Component, that is a child of at least 10 other components i call this subscribe:

```
  getAvatar() {
    this.userService.getAvatar(this.channelId)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.avatar = res;
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
        this.cdr.markForCheck();
      });
  }
```

OBS: Im using the `OnPush` changeDetection strategy

And in another component i have a function that changes this profile picture inside the link:

```
this.userService.changeProfilePicture(picture, this.myChannelId)
      .subscribe(
        () => {
          this.loading.hide();
          this.userService.getAvatar(this.id);
          this.screenService.showToastMessage('Foto de perfil alterada.', true);
        }
```

As you can see, im recalling the `getAvatar()` function that returns a BehaviorSubject to generate another link and the AvatarComponent doenst detect the change of the behaviorSubject, what im doing wrong ?

And theres another way to recall the `getAvatar()` function of all the AvatarComponent instances to reload each avatar instance ?

OBS2: I tried to use `of` rxjs operator, creating a `new Observable()`, tried the `Subject` class, all of those seems to not get detected by the subscribe inside the AvatarComponent

OBS3: I tried to get the AvatarComponent with `@ViewChild()` and call this `this.avatarCmp.getAvatar();` to reload the avatar, but reloads just one instance of the Avatar Component

Comment: You’re creating a new subject every time. So of course the components don’t know about each other’s subject. Has nothing to do with change detection. You need to have a single unchanging subject they both use and call the next method on it to update it

Comment: But if i do this ``return of(`${link}?${new Date().getTime()}`)`` it is going to return a new Observable or emits just a new value to the same observable ?

Comment: there needs to be one observable / subject. If you keep creating a new one every time, then how would they ever know about each other's value

Answer (score 0):

your service needs to be more like this:

```
  private avatarSource = new BehaviorSubject(`${link}?${new Date().getTime()}`);
  avatar$ = this.avatarSource.asObservable();
  setAvatar(channelId): BehaviorSubject<string> {
    this.avatarSource.next(`${link}?${new Date().getTime()}`);
  }
```

then you need to subscribe to avatar$ and update with setAvatar

Comment: but the URL receives differents channelId

Comment: then you need to show how that channel id is actually used in your method. in the code you posted it's just a parameter